# Raspberry Pi and lirc communication

Tags: python

So I've been working with lirc and pylirc and am looking at trying to communicate between 2 PIs using this technology.  My question is how fast can I expect communication being if sending a single "button press" vs several sequential "button presses".  My follow on question to that is how should the remote be configured to speed this communication up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the maths behind the speed but of the order of 4000bps seems to be the maximum data rate for typical IR remote devices.

E.g. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/30498.pdf

I presume this limit is to do with the 38kHz (or about) carrier wave.

IR devices without modulation can talk at 4Mbps (FIR) over limited distances.

E.g. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1830811.pdf